# Cocoa App Renders Differently on Macbook Pro vs Mac Mini

Tags: macos, cocoa, position, nsimageview

Perhaps I'm going crazy here, but I have a desktop mac application which, in one of its windows, has an `NSImageView` placed in a specific spot (using Interface Builder).

When I run the app on a Mac Mini it appears in the right spot.  But when I run it on a Macbook Pro the image view is offset quite noticeably.

I've tried on both Lion and Snow Leopard on two different macbook pros and two different mac minis.  The OS version doesn't seem to be a factor.  It seems the only difference is that one machine is a laptop and the other is a desktop, but I have no idea why this would affect the positioning of elements.

Is there any reason an app's UI elements would not appear in the right spot when running on a laptop vs desktop?

Or perhaps there's another reason this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your display is smaller on the Mac Mini and the window is larger than the display then it could be automatically resized. If that is the case then you should look at the view's autoresize mask to make sure they are correct.